# Optimize jquery code for toggling

Tags: jquery, optimization

I have a carousel slider, which have three static "dots" in the corner, one for each slide.
When the slide is active, the corresponding dot is white. When inactive, the dot is grey.
I have made this possible with this code below, but Im new to Jquery so Im looking if this can be shortened.

Is it possible to rewrite this code to be shorter?

I have this in the HTML:

```
<a id="th_1" class="thumb act"></a>
<a id="th_2" class="thumb"></a>
<a id="th_3" class="thumb"> </a>
```

Then I have this in jquery, at the top of the document:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

            $('#th_1').click(function(){
                $('#carousel').carousel(0); //go to slide1
                $('#th_1').addClass('act');
                $('#th_2').removeClass('act');
                $('#th_3').removeClass('act');
            ;})     

            $('#th_2').click(function(){
                $('#carousel').carousel(1); //go to slide 2
                $('#th_1').removeClass('act');
                $('#th_2').addClass('act');
                $('#th_3').removeClass('act');
            ;}) 

            $('#th_3').click(function(){
                $('#carousel').carousel(2); //go to slide 3
                $('#th_1').removeClass('act');
                $('#th_2').removeClass('act');
                $('#th_3').addClass('act');
            ;})
```

Then, I also have this below code for when the slides are rotating themselves, without clicks (because I need to change the dots when this happens as well).

```
$('#carousel_slide_1').hasClass('active')(function(){
                $('#th_1').addClass('act');
                $('#th_2').removeClass('act');
                $('#th_3').removeClass('act');
            });

$('#carousel_slide_2').hasClass('active')(function(){
                $('#th_1').removeClass('act');
                $('#th_2').addClass('act');
                $('#th_3').removeClass('act');
            });

$('#carousel_slide_3').hasClass('active')(function(){
                $('#th_1').removeClass('act');
                $('#th_2').removeClass('act');
                $('#th_3').addClass('act');
            });
```

The class "active" is on a div, which contains the slide. When the slide is active, this class is added through another carousel script to the div. So above I check if the div has this class, and if so, I change the class of the "dot".

The class "act" is simply a background change of the "dot" which makes it white in color, if the class is set. If removed, color of dot is grey.

Hope I haven't forgotten anything. If so, I will update this question.
Thanks

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first piece of code you can just use the `index()` function and a generic class like `thumb` as you have.

```
$('.thumb').click(function(){
    $('#carousel').carousel($(this).index());
    $('.thumb').removeClass('act');
    $(this).addClass('act');
});
```

The second piece of code doesn't seem right for what you're trying to do. The idea is to create a function or object to handle these events where you can pass values and the you just call those functions within the jQuery event. I hope this makes sense.
I wrote a tutorial a while ago on how to create a slider in jQuery, it might be useful.
http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/07/01/how-to-create-a-slideshow-plugin-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".thumb").click(function() {
    $('#carousel').carousel($(this).index());
    $(this).addClass("act").siblings().removeClass("act");
});​
```

- you just need to bind to the `.thumb` class, and that will attach a click handler to all matches.
- you can get the `.index` of the clicked one, and use that to invoke your carousel.
- the clicked one gets the class, the other ones (*siblings*) get the class removed.

You can use that pattern to shorten the rest of your implementation.

Comment: Hmm, I am trying this now, but isn't working right away. I will look more into it but maybe you could see the problem? Nothing happens on click, and suddenly firebug says "undefined" on all the code when debugging.

Comment: You could sandbox it in jsfiddle.net and provide the link here.

Comment: Even if I have an alert("hello") before your snippet, the alert wont execute unless I remove all your code.

Comment: Which version of jQuery? and there must be a syntax error in there. jslint.com can help you find it.

Comment: Hmmm. I would still be curious to know why my code didn't work. If `.siblings()` was not working then that is probably because the DOM structure you have posted is not the actual.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

is equivalent to

```
$(function(){
```

See http://api.jquery.com/ready/